# Using two different slugs on a route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, slug

I'm upgrading an old procedural site to laravel 5.2, and I'm struggling with the old routes I made.

On this website, the routes were made like this : `{user_slug}/{content_slug}.html`. For the moment, I use [cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable) to generate the slugs, but I'm open to another one if this one cannot meet my needs.

I have two questions :

- Can I make the `content-slug` unique, but per user ?
- How can I write the route and the controller in order to match the correct user slug ad the correct content slug ?

Answer (score 1):

I have not done this myself but I believe there would be a way in the [validation rules to do this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-unique). Here is an untested rough draft to check content_slug in the posts table but only check uniqueness where the user_id field equals a variable:

```
'content_slug' => "unique:posts,content_slug,NULL,id,user_id,$user->id"
```

Depending on who you ask, they may advise you (either instead of or as well as doing the above) to set up a key in the database based on the user_id and content_slug fields. This way the database returns an error if an insert is attempted as well as gives a performance boost when running a query off that index. Queries off of an index can literally give an exponential performance increase.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at it and try to implement.